# How to generate a random number in a JSON's field

Tags: angularjs

Here is my JSON. In field of Corelation Id, I want to generate a random number, how can I do that? I am using this function ->  **${__Random(1, 10000)}** but its not working, any suggestion please.

```
"LoginRequest": {
                 "Header": {
                  "CMMHeader": {
                    "CorrelationId":  ${__Random(1, 10000)},
                  }
                },
                     "ClientContext": {"UserName": "user102@domain503.com"},
                     "UserName": theUsername,
                      "UserPassword": thePassword

                    }
                  }
```

Comment: How is it not working? What result do you get and what result do you expect to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try pure JavaScript's `Math.random()`

```js
var json = {
  random: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10000)
}

console.log(json);
```